# FileMaker WebDirect Visual Glitch

Tags: user-interface, filemaker

I'm having an issue in FileMaker WebDirect where the first row in a list view (subsummary section) appears too high and leaves a blank beneath it. It also leaves a blank spot near the bottom as well.

[image: The visual glitch I mentioned]

It doesn't happen on every view, but it does happen consistently. For example, if I select the records for "John Doe" the glitch will always happen, while it will never happen when I select the records for "Jane Doe". The glitch isn't happening in FileMaker Pro and I haven't tested it yet in FileMaker Go. There doesn't seem to be anything about the records themselves that would cause this either. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not a programming question. You are much better off taking this to one of the FileMaker forums and when you do, add some info on your OS, FileMaker Server and target browser.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will do that.